# rename multiple xml file based on content using windows batch script recursively

Tags: batch-file

Hi i have a requirement , And im very new to batch scripting. I have multiple xml files in a folder with name APJ01.xm APJ02.xml....APJ0n.xml. I have to rename all these xml based on content inside the tag value 976064101. Here i have to pull 976064101 and rename this with that corresponding XML file. I have tried this starting to pull the value inside the tag

```
@ECHO OFF
SET InFile=C:\ramesh_personal\WIN_SRC\APJ_01.txt

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (
  'FINDSTR "<SOM_SalesOrderID>" "%InFile%" ^| FINDSTR "</SOM_SalesOrderID>"'
) DO CALL :FindString "%%A"
pause
GOTO :eof

:FindString
SET String=%~1
SET String=%String:*wordA =%
SET String=%String: wordB=`%
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=`" %%A IN ('ECHO.%String%') DO ECHO.%%A]
GOTO :eof
```

But this is not giving the value , its saying file line 1 is too long.

Can some one give me an idea on this

Comment: My XML file is very big , sample content is like this ::  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><NewDataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SalesOrder><SOM_SalesOrderID>976064101</SOM_SalesOrderID>

Comment: Please stop posting code snippets in comments as it becomes a bit unreadable; [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28106690/edit) rather.

Comment: JosefZ , i have removed the code from comments , sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

This script could work:

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
SET "InFile=C:\ramesh_personal\WIN_SRC\APJ_01.txt"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (
  'FINDSTR "<SOM_SalesOrderID>" "%InFile%" ^| FINDSTR "</SOM_SalesOrderID>"'
  ) DO (
    SET "String=%%A"
    CALL :FindString
)

pause

ENDLOCAL
GOTO :eof

:FindString
SET "String=%String:*<SOM_SalesOrderID>=%"
SET "String=%String:</SOM_SalesOrderID>=`%"
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=`" %%X IN ('ECHO %String%') DO (
  ECHO %%X]
) 
GOTO :eof
```

Note:

- `disabledelayedexpansion` for if a line contains `!`
- quoting all `set "variable=value"`, e.g. `SET "String=%String:*<SOM_SalesOrderID>=%"`
- `CALL :FindString` instead of `CALL :FindString "%%A"`
- `%%X` different `%%variable` in (implicit) embedded `FOR` loop within `:FindString` procedure

**Edit:** get all files in a directory

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

SET "InPath=C:\ramesh_personal\WIN_SRC"

For /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /B "%InPath%\*.txt"') do (           
  SET "InFile=%InPath%\%%i"

  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (
    'FINDSTR "<SOM_SalesOrderID>" "%InPath%\%%i" ^| FINDSTR "</SOM_SalesOrderID>"'
    ) DO (
      set "OuName=x"
      SET "String=%%A"
      CALL :FindString
      )            
  )

)
:endlocal
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:FindString
SET "String=%String:*<SOM_SalesOrderID>=%"
SET "String=%String:</SOM_SalesOrderID>=`%"
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=`" %%X IN ('ECHO %String%') DO (
  rem ECHO %%X
  set "OuName=%%X"
  call :renFile "%InFile%"
) 
GOTO :eof

:renFile
  echo "%~f1" "%~dp1%OuName%%~x1
GOTO :eof
```

`FINDSTR`: *line is too long* message could be solvable by reading a file line-by-line:

```
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (
    'type  "%InPath%\%%i" ^|FIND "<SOM_SalesOrderID>" ^| FIND "</SOM_SalesOrderID>"'
    ) DO (
```

What is the  line delimiter in your files? DOS-like `CrLf`, UNIX-like `Lf` or MAC-like `Cr`?

**Addendum**: Limitations: Although FIND can be used to scan large files, it will not detect any string that is positioned more than **1070** characters along a single line (with no carriage return) This makes it of limited use in searching binary or `XML` file types.

---

**Edit II**: according to [this article on FINDSTR 'Line Length limits'](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr-escapes.html): *Files specified as a command line argument or via the /F:FILE option have no known line length limit*, but *Piped data and Redirected input is limited to 8191 bytes per line*.

So get rid of redirected input from

```
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (
    'FINDSTR "<SOM_SalesOrderID>" "%InPath%\%%i" ^| FINDSTR "</SOM_SalesOrderID>"'
    ) DO (
```

and use next command instead:

```
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (
    'FINDSTR "<SOM_SalesOrderID>" "%InPath%\%%i"'
    ) DO (
```

However, ensure that next command works as expected (first and foremost):

```
 FINDSTR "<SOM_SalesOrderID>" "C:\ramesh_personal\WIN_SRC\APJ_01.txt"
```

If not the case, consider switching to another scripting language (PowerShell, VBScript or JScript)

---

**Edit III** With some unclear, dark particularities in procedure `:FindOuName` this works

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

SET "InPath=D:\bat\files"

For /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /B "%InPath%\*.XML"') do (           
  SET "InFile=%InPath%\%%i"
  @echo InFile "%InPath%\%%i"
  set "OuName=x"
  for /L %%G in (2, 1, 20) do (
    CALL :InnerLoop %%G %%i
  )
  call :renFile "%InPath%\%%i"
)
:endlocal
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:InnerLoop
  if "%OuName%"=="x" ( 
    for /F "usebackq tokens=%1* delims=<" /F %%A in ("%InPath%\%2") do ( 
        SET "String=x%%Ay"
        CALL :FindOuName %%G
    )
  )            
goto :eof

:FindOuName
rem @echo on
SET "String=%String:>y=€€€y%"
SET "String=%String:"=řřř%"
if not "%String%"=="xy" (
  rem   echo %1 "%String:&=^&%"   
  if  "%String:~0,18%"=="xSOM_SalesOrderID>" (
    set "OuName=%String:*xSOM_SalesOrderID>=%"
  ) 
)
@echo off
GOTO :eof

:renFile
  if not "%OuName%"=="x" ( 
     echo RENAME "%~f1" "%OuName:y=%%~x1"
  )
GOTO :eof
```

**Output**:

```
d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28106690.bat
InFile "D:\bat\files\APJ_02.xml"
RENAME "D:\bat\files\APJ_02.xml" "976065279.xml"
InFile "D:\bat\files\APJ_02formatted.xml"
RENAME "D:\bat\files\APJ_02formatted.xml" "976065279.xml"
InFile "D:\bat\files\sl.xml"
```

---

**Edit IV** Definitive version with next changes:

- home-made counter `%ii%` instead of `for /L %%G ...` loop
- simplified procedure `:FindOuName`: attended an occurrence of `"` double quotes in actually tested XML tag
- made public # of iterations and whether reached max. limit of tokens in a FOR command (31)

The script:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "InPath=D:\bat\files"

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /B "%InPath%\*.XML"') do (           
  set "InFile=%InPath%\%%i"
  echo(
  echo InFile "%InPath%\%%i"
  set /A "ii=0"
  set "String=noForLoop"
  set "OuName=noNewName"
  call :InnerLoop
  call :renFile "%InPath%\%%i"
  rem pause >nul
)
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:InnerLoop
  set /A "ii+=1"
  set "String=noForLoop"
   if "%OuName%"=="noNewName" ( 
    for /F "usebackq tokens=%ii%* delims=<" /F %%A in ("%InFile%") do (
      set "String=x%%Ay"
      call :FindOuName
    )
  ) else ( 
     goto :eof
  )
if "%String%"=="noForLoop" goto :eof
if %ii% LSS 31 (
   goto :InnerLoop
) else (
   echo Max. limit of tokens in a FOR command reached
) 
goto :eof

:FindOuName
  set "String=%String:"='%"
  rem echo %ii% "%String:~0,18%"
  if "%String:~0,18%"=="xSOM_SalesOrderID>" (
      set "OuName=%String:*xSOM_SalesOrderID>=%"
  ) 
GOTO :eof

:renFile
  if not "%OuName%"=="noNewName" ( 
      echo RENAME "%~f1" "%OuName:y=%%~x1"
      echo SOM_SalesOrderID found in iteration #%ii%
  ) else (
      echo SOM_SalesOrderID not found in %ii% iterations
  )
GOTO :eof
:: end of batch script
```

*Output*:

```
d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28106690.bat

InFile "D:\bat\files\APJ_02.xml"
RENAME "D:\bat\files\APJ_02.xml" "976065279.xml"
SOM_SalesOrderID found in iteration #5

InFile "D:\bat\files\APJ_02formatted.xml"
RENAME "D:\bat\files\APJ_02formatted.xml" "976065279.xml"
SOM_SalesOrderID found in iteration #3

InFile "D:\bat\files\smLayoutFormatted.xml"
SOM_SalesOrderID not found in 3 iterations

InFile "D:\bat\files\smLayoutRaw.xml"
Max. limit of tokens in a FOR command reached
SOM_SalesOrderID not found in 31 iterations
```

FYI: the `smLayoutRaw.xml` is my *Start menu layout* exported by

```
POWERSHELL -NonInteractive -Command Export-StartLayout –As XML –Path .\files\smLayoutRaw.xml
```

and `*Formatted.xml` = files rearranged to hold one XML tag in one line

Comment: Hi Josefz, I was trying your script but the file is big one so it throwed the below error. can i send u the xml file .C:\ramesh_personal\WIN_SRC>pg7.bat
FINDSTR: Line 1 is too long.
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Hi josefz, how to read file of that long , im assuming the line delimiter to be dos crlf,can you tell me how to avoid that error line is too long

Comment: Hi josefz, im stuck at this point . how do i overcome this limitation using windows batch script .   Addendum**: Limitations: Although FIND can be used to scan large files, it will not detect any string that is positioned more than **1070** characters along a single line (with no carriage return) This makes it of limited use in searching binary or `XML` file type.

Comment: Hi Josefz, That didnt work , not throwing any output.Cant we cut that whole line till this </SOM_SalesOrderID> store it in some temp file now get the value from this and rename the xml file . Can we try this logic ?

Comment: `FINDSTR /I "<SOM_SalesOrderID>" "C:\ramesh_personal\WIN_SRC\APJ_01.txt"` should work (note the `/I` switch). Not like that I'm at the end of my rope :)

Comment: Hi Josefz , I have changed according to what you have said its not throwing any output or shall i mail u the xml file for understanding better .                                                                             For /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /B "%InPath%\*.xml"') do (           
  SET "InFile=%InPath%\%%i"

  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (
    'FINDSTR /I "<SOM_SalesOrderID>" "%InPath%\%%i"'
    ) DO (

Comment: _for understanding better_: upload the xml file to a public online file storage, put a link for download  here

Comment: JosefZ , i have uploaded file in wiki upload , can you try downloading and check this , http://www.wikiupload.com/ZYR2VIQ35NI310E

Comment: JosefZ, U did it , HATS OFF TO U :) . Im getting the output what i wanted , but im totally blank of whats happening inside the :FindOuName procedure. Can you please explain ":FindOuName" block in detail, so that if i get some other requirement i would try to change.

Comment: Hi JosefZ , I have an addition requirement to this . I just need to change the file name like this , example:: APJ01.xml to APJ_976064101_20150113222650.xml  , That number is what we are getting from inside the tag and along with that time-stamp needed to be appended . Can you tell how can this be added.

Comment: `DIR` command gives file time stamps. Generating `yyyymmdd-hhmm` _formated_ timestamp of a given file is locale dependent. Modify `for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=.: " %%G in ('dir "%InPath%\%%i" ^|find "%%i"') do echo %%I%%H%%G-%%J%%K`. Gives me `20150125-2107` for next `dir` output: `25.01.2015  21:07            14 256 APJ_02.xml`